# Error locating libraries when using gmp

Tags: c++, clang, gmp

So I have been writing a c++ program and in it it handles integers too large for the inbuilt long long. No problem, I'll just use a bignum library. So I get GMP, utter those three magic commands "./configure, make, make install" and start using it. I use `#include "gmpxx.h"` as specified in the docs for a c++ program. Compiling it, GPP finds an error in gmpxx.h as apparently gmp.h can't be located using angles and quotes should be used instead in the include statement in gmpxx.h. Upon changing the angles to quotes, however, I am surprised to discover that something has gone wrong, I think with 'make'. It says:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___gmpz_clear", referenced from:
      __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>::~__gmp_expr() in primality-3fd487.o
  "___gmpz_cmp_si", referenced from:
      __gmp_binary_equal::eval(__mpz_struct const*, long) in primality-3fd487.o
  "___gmpz_init", referenced from:
      __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>::__gmp_expr() in primality-3fd487.o
  "___gmpz_set_d", referenced from:
          __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>::assign_d(double) in   primality-3fd487.o
      "___gmpz_tdiv_r_ui", referenced from:
          __gmp_binary_modulus::eval(__mpz_struct*, __mpz_struct const*, long) in     primality-3fd487.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Does anyone know how to stop either of these errors occurring?

Comment: By default `make install` should put the GMP library in `/usr/local/`. When compiling and linking against it you may need to add `-I/usr/local/include` to your compiler flags and `-L/usr/local/lib64` or `-L/usr/local/lib` to the linker flags (in addition, and before `-lgmp -lgmpxx` of course)

Comment: @MarcGlisse added all of it :)

Comment: @Galik doing that allows me to use angles in the gmpxx.h file, but I still get the above error

Comment: Can you post the compiler command that produces that error?

Comment: @Galik `g++ /Users/Anon/Desktop/primality.cp -I/usr/local/include`

Comment: Try this: `g++ -o primality -I/usr/local/include /Users/Anon/Desktop/primality.cpp -L/usr/local/lib64 -L/usr/local/lib -lgmp -lgmpxx`

Comment: @Galik Thank you very much! After a bit of tweaking I finally managed to get it working. Now the actual program doesn't work but I'll get there :P